Using RunOaktonCommands in combination with a test using a WebApplicationFactory results in a ObjectDisposedException
I have the following program:
public sealed class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(params string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            await using var app = builder
                .Build();

            app.UseRequestLocalization(
                new RequestLocalizationOptions
                {
                    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("nl-NL"),
                });

            await app.RunOaktonCommands(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
}

With the following Test:
    public class Tests : WebApplicationFactory<WebApplication1.Program>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseEnvironment("UnitTest");
            builder.ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddConsole());
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            Server.PreserveExecutionContext = true;
            using var client = CreateClient();
            
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }

This results in a failed test with the following error log:
 Test1
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 17
   Duration: 279 ms

  Message: 
System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

  Stack Trace: 
ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
WebApplicationFactory`1.get_Server()
Tests.Test1() line 23
GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
DelegatingTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)

  Standard Output: 

[red]Invalid usage[/][yellow]Unknown argument or flag for value --environment=UnitTest[/]
run - Start and run this .Net application
└── Start and run this .Net application
    └── dotnet run -- run 
        ├── [-c, --check]
        ├── [-e, --environment <environment>]
        ├── [-v, --verbose]
        ├── [-l, --log-level 
        │   Trace|Debug|Information|Warning|Error|Critical|None]
        └── [--config:<prop> <value>]

                                                                                
                                  Usage   Description                           
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                          [-c, --check]   Run the environment checks before     
                                          starting the host                     
      [-e, --environment <environment>]   Use to override the ASP.Net           
                                          Environment name                      
                        [-v, --verbose]   Write out much more information at    
                                          startup and enables console logging   
                      [-l, --log-level    Override the log level                
  Trace|Debug|Information|Warning|Error                                         
                        |Critical|None]                                         
              [--config:<prop> <value>]   Overwrite individual configuration    
                                          items                                 
                                                                                

If I change "app.RunOaktonCommands(args)" into "app.RunAsync()" the unit test succeeds. So something in RunOaktonCommands is either requesting a disposed object or disposing an object prematurely.
Am I missing something, am I doing some configuration wrong, is the cause of this issue the warning by Oakton, or is this something out of my control?

Someone pointed me to an extra Oakton command which disables the whole argument handling:
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("UnitTest");
        OaktonEnvironment.AutoStartHost = true;
    }

I'm still not entirely sure WHY, but this resolves the issue of the ObjectDisposedException.
